# What polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}[x]$ has splitting field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Tags: finite-fields, splitting-field

What polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}[x]$ has splitting field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Suppose $m \mid n$. I know that the extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} / \mathbb{F}_{p}$ can be obtained as the splitting field of $x^{p^n} -x$. Similarly for $\mathbb{F}_{p^m} / \mathbb{F}_{p}$. Am I right in thinking that there should be some polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m}[x]$, such that it's splitting field is $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$? Is $f(x) = (x^{p^n} -x)/(x^{p^m} -x)$? Does this polynomial really have coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$? (Because it seems like it has coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.)

Thank you!

Comment: As $\Bbb F_p\subseteq\Bbb F_{p^m}$ then a polynomial over $\Bbb F_p$ als must have coefficients in $\Bbb F_{p^m}$. There are many polynomials with splitting field $\Bbb F_{p^n}$. I contend the easiest is still $X^{p^n}-X$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know that's not a very _long_ answer, but it is an answer. Why did you put it as a comment?

Comment: You are right, I completely failed to see that $X^{p^n} - X$ is actually an answer...